# How to verify a locally installed version of a module is the one used by pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have manually installed `datatable` (from `h2o.ai`) https://github.com/h2oai/datatable from `HEAD` of master

```
 make build
 make install
```

They were successful.  However when running pip3 freeze I see the (v old) *default* version (`0.6.0`) that had been installed via

```
pip3 install datatable
```

some months back:

```
$pip3 freeze | grep datatable

datatable==0.6.0
```

I am uncertain whether:

- the *locally built* version of datatable is not being used
- the *locally built* version of datatable ***is*** being used but not reported by `pip3`

  - if that were the case: how to verify the locally built/installed version were being used (or not)

Tips appreciated.

**Updates**

Based on (great) comments below:

```
import datatable then print(datatable.__version__)

 0.6.0
```

But the `datatable.__file__` shows the *local* version:

```
In [3]: print(datatable.__file__)
/git/datatable/datatable/__init__.py
```

Does this possibly mean that the local installation  *is* being used - but that the version reported by that locally built one is still the same (v old) one that was published to pip repositories months earlier?

Comment: why not `import datatable` then `print(datatable.__version__)`. Try `dir(datatable)` to make sure there's a version attribute in there.

Comment: use a virtualenv

Comment: I will try that .. but there is *no* general way to find a version (not all libraries export that identifier `__version__`).: I'd like to know the answer not just for this particular library

Comment: Looking at Makefile this local build was installed with `pip` (python2.7) I guess that's why it is not visible for pip3. Try if `pip freeze` will show correct version.

Comment: Better, use `datatable.__file__` - that will show the location of the imported file

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur  How did you find that :  I see `python` referenced in the `Makefile` but in same terminal i just did `$python --version  Python 3.6.4`

Comment: @javadba Pip operates on either Python 2 or Python 3 depending on your current context (in most cases it's Python 2.7, I've just assumed to early)

Comment: @duhaime  That was helpful: pls see update to the question.

Comment: yes, the version is unchanged, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look precisely at the module being used, the best way, as mentioned by @duhaime is to use `import datatable; print(datatable.__file__)`.

If your local installation was done correctly, then you should also make sure that 1) the location where you installed it is in your `PYTHONPATH`, 2) that if it is, the path is placed **before** that of the standard paths (lookup is sequential).
An easy way to check that it is in the path if you don't know where to look is just to uninstall the version installed through pip.

**EDIT**

Based on the edit to the question, yes, the version is still the same (see [here](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/blob/master/datatable/__version__.py))

Comment: I am going to update the version to `0.6.5` in my local `git` clone

Comment: `$ipython -c "import datatable; print(datatable.__version__)"    0.6.5`